# Compile/Link a C++ project using python

Tags: c++

So i have a somewhat large C++ project that I want to compile.Previously I used Code::Blocks, but now I want more control about what's happening behind the scenes. However making makefiles was just too complex for me!!

What I want is this: Can i create a python script that acts as a makefile, if so how?!

In the makefile I want to search for all *.cpp files on certain directories and then invoke g++ to compile/link them.

EDIT: sorry i forgot to mention i also have headers and want custom g++ parameters

Comment: _"However making makefiles was just too complex for me!!"_ I'm afraid doing this in a python script will become even more complex. Use the tools that were made for doing this specifically.

Comment: the problem is i'm confused with the makefile syntax... and python is much more familiar to me!

Comment: If you only need to collect all cpp files, compile them and link all the stuff together, what is the problem to do this? If the job is so stupid, simply do it. I have no idea why make is to complex for that and I have no idea what python can do in this very very simple question.

Comment: OMG i don't want to hardcode all 50+ g++ commands if you understand what i mean!

Comment: I need only 4 lines... see my answer. I can't believe that python solves that in a smaller solution :-)

Comment: In addition: Programming is not only code hacking. It also needs some more experience if the problem is not trivial. A bit know how for build tool chains, source code management, debugging and a lot more is part of the job. Ignoring make good startpoint to be a bad programmer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [scons](http://www.scons.org/)

It looks like what you need

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
#default target
all: prog

#auto dependency

include $(OBJ_FILES:.o=.d)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $*.cpp -o $*.o
    $(CXX) -MM $(CXXFLAGS) $*.cpp > $*.d
    @mv -f $*.d $*.d.tmp
    @sed -e 's|.*:|$*.o:|' < $*.d.tmp > $*.d
    @sed -e 's/.*://' -e 's/\\$$//' < $*.d.tmp | fmt -1 | \
    sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/$$/:/' >> $*.d
    @rm -f $*.d.

#set ld flags eg for libs
LDFLAGS = -lsdl2 -lglew -lgl

#set cxxflags for all debug options and others
CXXFLAGS= -g -Wall

#collect all cpp files:
CPP_FILES := $(shell find . -type f -name '*.cpp')

#get the object file names for them
OBJ_FILES := $(CPP_FILES:.cpp=.o)

#and link all togeter
prog: $(OBJ_FILES)
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)  -o $@ $^
```

Comment: and what about headers, compiler parameters or libraries?! I need -wall -g, headers and -lSDL2 -lGLEW -lGL!

Comment: you told us that you only want to collect all cpp files and compile and link! And what do you mean is with reading the manual? Would you please try to start asking good questions? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it doesn't change the fact that i understand little from what you just wrote in your answer, so it will be hard for me to expand on that, if i want any more functionality! It may be easier for you, but not for me!

Comment: You get a first solution. I can't teach you here online. What is your expectation? Why you don't start reading the manual? Nobody will read the manual to you.